# Editor on Ubuntu

Tags: dconf

Why does the system and the desktop not appear in the Configuration Editor ?

[image: problem]

Comment: I haven't used dconf edior or gsettings editor myself but what happens when you click down lower on the left pane say to the `schemas` section? Do variables begin to appear?

Comment: No....Do not appear